# What is the difference between args and runtimeArgs in VSCode's launch.json?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

What is the difference between `args` and `runtimeArgs` in launch.json?

```
// Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable
"runtimeArgs": []
// Command line arguments passed to the program
"args": []
```

Is the program not the same thing as the runtime executable?

**Extra information and motivation behind the question:**

I am developing a nodejs application. In my `package.json`, I have a `start` script:

`"start": "electron ./src/Main/main.js arg2"`, and in my app code, I access `process.argv[2]` which gets me `arg2`, so when I run `npm start`, my app works as intended.

When I run the app from VSCode, however it doesn't, and the reason was that I wasn't supplying any additional arguments in `launch.json`. Where should I put those arguments? `process.argv` seems to contains the arguments provided in either `args` or `runtimeArgs` though it also sticks in some `--debug-brk` argument, which I don't want.

I want to be able to use `process.argv` consistently when I run the app from the command line (`npm start`) or start it from VSCode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is mostly explained in the [Node debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging#_launch-configuration-support-for-npm-and-other-tools):

> Instead of launching the Node.js program directly with node, you can use 'npm' scripts or other task runner tools directly from a launch configuration:
>
> - Any program available on the PATH (for example 'npm', 'mocha', 'gulp', etc.) can be used for the runtimeExecutable attribute [...]

**`runtimeExecutable` is not the program you want to debug, but the executable used to run it.** So it appears that `runtimeArgs` is to `runtimeExecutable` as `args` is to `program`.

If you're interested in how it works in detail, [here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.9.1/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/node/debugAdapter.ts#L41-L50) the relevant part of the `debugAdapter.ts` implementation.

Comment: I can't see any difference whether I put the `"x"` argument in `"runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "start", "x" ]` or in `"args": [ "x" ]`, it leads to the same result: `node run-script start x`. So, what makes the difference then?

Answer (score 6):

If you remove the attribute "program", the arguments are attached after another and you don't see any difference.

Consider following example, including "type" **and** "program":

```
         {
            
           "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [ 
                "--runInBand"                       
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true
        }
```

=> set "NODE_ENV=development" && "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --nolazy --inspect-brk=35238 **node_modules\jest-cli\bin\jest.js** --runInBand

- The **runtimeArg** "--nolazy" occurs **behind** node.exe (corresponds to **type**) and
- The **arg** "--runInBand" occurs **behind** jest.js (corresonds to **program**)

If you remove the attribute "program", the arguments are attached after another and you don't see any difference.

Comment: for me vscode debugging crash on debug start after adding flag "--experimental-worker" in npm script and forgot to add to lunch.json node config -- adding this to runtimeArgs array fix it.