# Debugging Jest on VS Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm trying to debug Jest unit tests using VS Code.  I have the following config file settings

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--inspect-brk",
            "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules//jest/bin/jest.js",
            "--runInBand"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
]
```

However when I run (F5) VS Code I get the following error

Error: AggregatedResult must be present after test run is complete

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

About debugging Jest unit tests using VSCode, create a the following file (path: *.vscode/launch.json*)

If you have created your app using *create-react-app*

```
  {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug tests watch mode",
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
          "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--watchAll=true"],
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "protocol": "inspector",
          "console": "integratedTerminal",
          "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you have created your app from scratch:

```
   {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Jest watch all tests",
          "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
          "args": [
            "--verbose",
            "-i",
            "--no-cache",
            "--watchAll"
          ],
          "console": "integratedTerminal",
          "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
      ]
    }
```

There are more configurations available, if you need more info check out:

- [Step by step guide (post)](https://www.basefactor.com/using-visual-studio-code-to-debug-jest-based-unit-tests)
- [Create react app official guide](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/debugging-tests)
- [Microsoft official guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-jest-tests)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the precise question, however this basic launch config for debugging Jest works for me, it's also simple to include Jest skip files

> ```
>     {
>       "type": "node",
>       "request": "launch",
>       "name": "Jest",
>       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
>       "args": [
>           "-i"
>       ],
>        "skipFiles": [
>         "<node_internals>/**/*.js", "node_modules",
>       ]
>     },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

@tmp dev, if you simply change `runtimeArgs` to `args` in your configuration, it would work:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Jest Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
            "--runInBand"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
]
```

`runtimeArgs` is to runtimeExecutable as `args` is to program. As you are launching Jest directly with node, in this case you should use `args` passing arguments to `node`. See the [Nodejs debugging docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) and [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207740/what-is-the-difference-between-args-and-runtimeargs-in-vscodes-launch-json) for more details.

**[2nd way]** Specify the actual program to run:

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Test",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "args": ["--runInBand", "--config=${workspaceFolder}/jest.config.js"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
  ]
```

**[3rd way]** If you would like to launch the debugger via npm (which is a runtimeExecutable), and your package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:unit:debug": "node --inspect-brk=9229 ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --no-cache --runInBand"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can launch the debugger using `runtimeArgs` like this in VS Code:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch via npm",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "test:unit:debug"],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using launch.json based on 
 https://www.basefactor.com/using-visual-studio-code-to-debug-jest-based-unit-tests
article, in particular example https://github.com/Lemoncode/jest-vs-code-debugging-example/blob/master/custom-solution-jest-config-file/01-implemented/.vscode/launch.json

The section of launch.json to debug single test (assuming that the configuration is located in ./config/test/jest.json):

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Jest debug current file",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
  "args": [
    "${fileBasename}",
    "-c",
    "./config/test/jest.json",
    "--verbose",
    "-i",
    "--no-cache",
    //"--watchAll"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```