# Debugging Jest Test Visual studio code

Tags: typescript, debugging, vue.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I want to debug tests written in Jest in visual studio code in newly created VueJs projects. Tests are written in typescript. I think that it is not related to the Vue.

I've already tried some samples on stack overflow but nothing worked. I still get this error:

**Jest encountered an unexpected token**

C:\src\vue-testing-sample\tests\unit\Caculator.spec.ts:1
({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Calculator } from "../../src/Calculator";
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)

Here is a test:

```
import { Calculator } from "../../src/Calculator";

describe("HelloWorld.vue", () => {
    it("adds two number", () => {
        const calculator = new Calculator();
        const result = calculator.add(1, 2);
        expect(result).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

and my configuration:

```
 "type": "node",
 "request": "launch",
 "name": "Jest All",
 "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
 "args": ["--runInBand"],
 "console": "integratedTerminal",
 "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
```

I can add that running tests from console from default Vue Webpack configuration works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563964/debugging-jest-on-vs-code

Answer (score 4):

This is my config for debugging Jest tests on VSCode, add this to your launch config in settings.json

```
"launch" : {
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": [
          "-i"
      ],
       "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js", "node_modules",
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Do you have typescript in your project?

Comment: Just JS, I'll do some more digging later and see if can get a typescript version working. Have you got a basic typescript project debugging OK without the Vue?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

screen.debug() has been my best solution!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).