# How to pass arguments when debugging Deno apps?

Tags: vscode-debugger, deno

Code:

```js
console.log(Deno.args[0])
console.log(Deno.args[1])
```

`launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "test",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "argA",
                "argB"
            ],
            "args": ["arg0", "arg1"],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229
        },
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Expected:

```
arg0
arg1
```

or

```
argA
argB
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between args and runtimeArgs in VSCode's launch.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207740/what-is-the-difference-between-args-and-runtimeargs-in-vscodes-launch-json) `{"runtimeArgs":["run","--inspect-wait"],"args":["arg0","arg1"]}` is what you're after.